# Detox build with Expo - "Error: Could not find build script in detox.configurations["ios.sim"].build"

Tags: react-native, expo, travis-ci, detox

**Goal:**
I would like to be able to run detox tests for an expo app with Travis.

I created a bare-bones expo app that successfully runs a single detox test on my local machine. After pushing to git and running on Travis, all dependencies install successfully and then the Travis build scripts fail with the following error.

**Error:**
`Error: Could not find build script in detox.configurations["ios.sim"].build`

**Issue:**
It looks like the issue occurs because there isn't a "build" entry in the "ios.sim" configuration for "detox" in `package.json`. For a non-expo React Native project with detox, the corresponding `.xcodeproject` or `.xxworkspace` can be built directly. Expo doesn't have a `.xcodeproject` or `.xcworkspace` - what to put for the "build" configuration for an Expo project? While there is an Exponent.the app provided by the expo to run tests with detox, I don't see any `.xcodeproject or .xcworkspace` to build with.

**Repro steps:**

- Clone git@github.com:bryanboyko/expo-detox-travis-3.git
- `cd expo-detox-travis-3`
- `npm install`
- `./setup.sh`
- `detox test`
- push to a new branch and create a PR to see travis build

**Travis failure log:**
https://travis-ci.com/bryanboyko/expo-detox-travis-3/builds/151879107